# Jest testing module.exports instead of export default of a class that extends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs

Trying to test module.exports that equals a createReactClass. I have only tested components that export default of a class.

I have tried to approach it the way I have with the export default but no Joy on it.

```
//myfile.jsx


module.exports = createReactClass({ some additional content here })


//myfile.spec.jsx


let  createReactClass = require("../myfile")

let props = {
    Hello: "hello"
};

    it('testing', (done) => {
        const component = shallow(<createReactClass {...props}/>);
    });
```

The above test is not rendering what I expect. It is

No errors just not rendering the component

Comment: Capitalize C as CreateReactClass. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: Seriously!!!! Thanks! I did not realize that would be the problem. Now it jumped into the render! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor issue it seems. Capitalize `C` as `CreateReactClass` because react thinks its normal html tag but its not so not rendered.
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized